# Does /v2.1/me/friends show Testers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does the `/v2.1/me/friends` request show testers? It appears not, as I added a tester (not test user) and confirmed it and he isn't listed. Does the app have to be live to get any data from that request?

Comment: Have both you and the Tester granted the app user_friends permission?

Comment: Yes, we both have accepted.

Comment: Then file a bug a https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

If the tester is one of the requesting user's friends, then this should be a bug. If they aren't friends, why should he be shown?

If the first thing is the case, file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs